# Explode string then parse delimiter for a variable

Tags: php

If I have a string like:

```
$string = "the year is currently <!--CODE echo date('Y'); CODE-->, it's been a good year."
```

Where in the above string `<!--CODE` and `CODE-->` were the delimiters and everything in-between the delimiters is taken out of context and made into a string. then implode it back together again but with the delimiters removed and eval() applied to the string made from within the delimiters.

Presumably I should be using explode and implode to split and join the string but how to define and parse the delimiter for a variable as I've described I have  no idea about.

If anyone could help me out with this I'd really appreciate it thank you.

EDIT: Perhaps I should be clear on one thing. $string in the example above is a database entry containing HTML and this HTML is echo'd to the end user but before it does, I want to process the database entry for the above mentioned HTML comments and parse the PHP code inside them accordingly. I can not simply store PHP in the database as it is either echoed in the document visible to all or the HTML comments are embedded in the document. I want to parse the database entry for the HTML comments containing PHP code so that I can separate the strings and use eval() on the string containing the PHP code.

Comment: use preg_split  for splitting the string ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu How would you suggest I use the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that:

```
$string = "the year is currently <!--CODE return date('Y'); CODE-->, it's been a good year.";

$string = preg_replace_callback('/<!--CODE(.*?)CODE-->/',
    function($groups) { return eval($groups[1]); },
    $string);

echo $string; // displays: "the year is currently 2014, it's been a good year."
```

Note that I changed 'echo' to 'return' in the embedded code. If you really need to use echo you would need to use output buffering to capture its output into the string.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that. Just 1 question, do I have to keep the function inline?

Comment: @TimDoyle You don't have to keep it inline; you can use any type of [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) reference, although the inline syntax is neatest.